# How to auto import on enter in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

When I type `Comment` and press enter for the suggested class, I get `\App\Models\Comment`. Instead. I want to explicitly import it i.e. `use App\Models\Comment`.

[image]

Comment: When you choose appropriate choice, press tab.

Comment: 1) Where do you enter such code (show an example of such file)? 2) As I understand it's not namespaced context (no namespace declared at the top of the file)? 3) And it works OK in other places (like your Controllers, or inside `App\Model\Comment` class, right)?

Comment: @LazyOne
1) I'm using laravel: `routes/web.php`.
2) Yes.
3) Yes, it works okay in controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the auto import works in namespaced context (in a controller or model classes) then it must be that specific context setting.

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS)`
2. `Editor | General | Auto Import`
3. Make sure that `PHP | Enable auto-import in file scope` option is enabled.

[image]